# Early Access to Async Action Results in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, async-await, asp.net-mvc-5

When we use async action in MVC like below example, post model data is available earlier than 10 seconds in view(here in 1 second) ? I confused, How data available in 1 seccond While fetching data take 10 seconds ???

for example:

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> GetPosts()
    {

        // ...
        IPost posts = await PostService.GetPosts();// assume this take 10 seconds
        // ...

        return View(model: posts);//BUT we return in 1 second! How posts model available in view for show to the user earlier than 10 seconds?
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't get to the `return` statement in 1 second. The method returns a `Task<ActionResult>` as soon as it reaches the first `await` expression which hasn't already completed. That task will not be completed (so you can't get its result) until your async method *does* reach the `return` statement.

But when the first thing you're awaiting completes, your async method will resume, continuing from where it left off until the next await, when it will "go to sleep" again (but without blocking a thread) until the awaitable has completed, etc.

That's the nature of async. You just need to distinguish between "the async method has returned a task" (which happens quickly) and "the async method has completed" (which often *doesn't* happen quickly).

It's hard to describe async thoroughly in just a few paragraphs - I suggest you read a good book, watch a video, or read a good tutorial. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) is a good starting point.

Comment: you say "but without blocking a thread", so request not blocked current thread and we reach to return in 1 second, thats true? if your answer is no, SO what is difference between Async action and not Async action?

Comment: @user197508: It returns to the caller - but ASP.NET won't give a result to the *client* until the task has completed. The difference is that while it's waiting for data, it's not tying up a thread - so if you have 10,000 requests executing concurrently, you can still get away with very few threads.

Comment: @Jun: So Async action benefit is when we use project in production with many users and many request in seccond which caused not blocked users when another user has a request? and we don't touch Async action benefits in development? thats true?

Comment: @user197508: It's not a matter of blocking users - it's a matter of how many threads are required at a time. But no, you would use async in development as well - it would be awful to try to change from sync to async just before deploying to production.

Comment: @Jun: Very Thanks for your attention.Asynchronous action methods are useful when an action must perform "Several Independent" long running operations, and we cannot use Async benefits where there are only "One" long running operation, like my question example. thats true?

Comment: @user197508: No, not at all. The long-running operation on the database doesn't need a thread running on your ASP.NET server, does it? So there could be thousands of database asynchronous operations running at the same time (one per request) but you wouldn't want one thread for each of those.

Comment: @Jun: we must use Async Only in non-CPU bound requests, acording to [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.100).aspx), so benefit in using Async is this we don't block cpu for another requests, and we create a new thread and send non-CPU bound request for continue to this new thread, thats true?

Comment: @user197508: I'm not quite sure why you keep calling me "Jun", but no, using async in CPU-bound tasks is generally not a good idea... although there are hybrid workloads where it can make sense.

Comment: Excuse me,Excuse me sir. 

Now problem solved for me.